# Error on installing Xampp apache on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp

I have been trying to install xampp (5.6.24) on ubuntu16.04, but I am encountering the following error-

Syntax error on line 136 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /opt/lampp/modules/mod_ssl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have tried searching the internet but am unable to find anything specifically for ubuntu.

Any suggestions might help.

Comment: Try to look here: http://serverfault.com/questions/791409/cannot-load-modules-mod-ssl-so-into-server-etc-httpd-modules-mod-ssl-so-undef

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem .Just comment out line 136 of httpd.conf and xampp will work fine for you but the catch is you cannot download packages from https servers .change

```
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

in httpd.conf to

```
    #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Comment: Thanks, out of expectation.